# Grid view with Datasource control

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0

Sir, 
    Im doing a project in asp.net 4.0 with c#.I my project i want to display datas from the database to the grid view using Data Source Control. But while doing it im getting an eror called "***The DataSourceID of 'GridView1' must be the ID of a control of type IDataSource.  A control with ID 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource' could not be found.***".
 My code is also givren below.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SPS_LeaveBalanceReport_DSO", Connect.con());
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReportMonth", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =
    SelectMonthDropDown.SelectedValue.ToString();
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReportYear", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =
    SelectYearDropDown.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();            

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "tab");    

GridView1.DataSourceID = SqlDataSource1.ToString();
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Please help me with error.,thanks In Advance.,

Answer (score 1):

change

```
GridView1.DataSourceID = SqlDataSource1.ToString();
```

to

```
GridView1.DataSourceID = SqlDataSource1.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is no where in your cod ejust replace the line

```
GridView1.DataSourceID = SqlDataSource1.ToString();
```

with

```
GridView1.DataSource=ds;
```

it will work

Comment: Hai Sir., Thank u for the Code. But it is still not working. The Error now im getting is "The DataSourceID of 'GridView1' must be the ID of a control of type IDataSource.  A control with ID 'System.Data.DataSet' could not be found."

Comment: change the property from DataSourceId to DataSource